# Showing A Form In Thread - C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Look at this code :

```
static Thread t1;
static ThreadStart ts1;

void my()
{
    this.Hide();
    Form2 frm2 = new From2();
    frm2.Show();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ts1 = new ThreadStart(my);
    t1 = new Thread(ts1);
    t1.Start();
}
```

In `my` function there are some codes witch hides this form and opens form2 but there is a problem. When `t1` runs and form2 is opened , the `t1` is done so form2 will be closed too !

What should I do to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need to use more than one thread for forms?  You've only got one user at a time.

Comment: No this is just an example . I'm doing something else ...

Comment: Hard to tell what you need to do based on an example.  Multiple threads for multiple forms is not generally a good idea, if you describe what you're trying to accomplish someone might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 2):

Do all UI calls on the UI thread. Always. Hide and open forms on the UI thread.

Comment: Like that: https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=winforms+call+on+ui+thread

Comment: I'm new in c# , my English is not good too can you make an example Please ?

Answer (score 0):

change your method :

```
void my()
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.Hide();
                Form frm2 = new Form();
                frm2.Show();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Effectively eliminating the Thread. Might as well leave it out then.